# Restart C++ Concurrency Agent?

Tags: c++, concurrency

Can I restart the [Concurrency Agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492627.aspx) object after it done his work?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is No.

If you look at the life cycle [described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd551463.aspx), you'll see the following:

> Agents have a set life cycle. The `concurrency::agent_status`
>   enumeration defines the various states of an agent. The following
>   illustration is a state diagram that shows how agents progress from
>   one state to another. In this illustration, solid lines represent
>   methods that you call from your application; dotted lines represent
>   methods that are called from the runtime.

[image]

This shows clearly that once your agent has entered the `done` or `cancelled` state, there's no way back.

Also, if you look at the [`agent::start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470900.aspx) documentation, you see this:

> Moves an agent from the **agent_created** state to the **agent_runnable** state, and schedules it for execution.

and this:

> An agent that has been canceled cannot be started.

Although this doesn't mention the **done** state, I've found from experience that once it's done, it's done. The state sequence diagram shows a one-way trip for all paths.